# Where to update a UI element if a Fragment in the main activity

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I have this activity that sets a fragment. After commiting I want to update a textView like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    settingsManager = SettingsManager(this)
    var mainFragment = MainFragment()
    mainFragment.arguments = intent.extras
    val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_view, mainFragment, "MAIN")
    transaction.commit()
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
    //initialize timer for the first time
    logMain("hello")
}

fun logMain(message: String) {
    val mainFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MAIN") as MainFragment
    mainFragment.textMainLog.setText(mainFragment.textMainLog.text.toString() + message + "\n")
    var scrollAmount = mainFragment.textMainLog.getLayout().getLineTop(mainFragment.textMainLog.getLineCount()) - mainFragment.textMainLog.getHeight()
    // if there is no need to scroll, scrollAmount will be <=0
    if (scrollAmount > 0)
        mainFragment.textMainLog.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount)
    else
        mainFragment.textMainLog.scrollTo(0, 0)
}
```

But I get following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ar.smshub/com.ar.smshub.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property textMainLog has not been initialized
```

So where can I safely update some UI element on the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the property textMainLog in your MainFragment is set as lateinit.

Notice that you're immediately setting the text of the textMainLog right after you commit the fragment. Make sure that your fragment is attached, its layout fully inflated before setting, and all the necessary references to the views are initialized before setting the views' properties.